# Issue on Solaris CC optimization flag

Tags: solaris, cc

May I ask a question about the CC compiler in Solaris environment.

I try to compile a Solaris release library with "-O" using Solaris CC compiler. I can compile the debug library previously using "-g".

However, when I change the "-g" to "-O", after some time, the compilation stop without any error. There is no output however.

I am thinking it is related to memory. So I try to compile a very simple cpp using -O flag. This time, the output is there.

May I know if any one has any idea on it? If it is a memory issue, can we use some commend or compile flag to solve it? Maybe increase the virtual memory assigned to CC?

Thanks,

Comment: What version of CC? What version of Solaris? How does the output of compilation looks like with -# flag added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could increase virtual memory by making a swapfile:

```
mkswap 4096M /where/you/want/your/swapfile

swap -a /where/you/want/your/swapfile
```

Alternatively,  you can run your truss your compilation to see exactly what's going on:

```
truss -f <build command>
```

Comment: "mkswap" doesn't exist and isn't required anyway on Solaris, I guess you mean `mkfile 4g /where/you/want/your/swapfile`